# Create a username from another table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a username from a table and insert it into a new table, i have a table called person, it has columns:

> first_name, last_name, address, phone, Email, availability_id, skills, commprefs, volunteer_id, username

Basically I want to concat the first and last name into a username and insert that username into a new table.

I created the table as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE user4 AS
SELECT * FROM person;
ALTER TABLE user4 ADD username VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL;
```

All that works, then I tried to create the user name with:

```
INSERT INTO user4(username) SELECT SUBSTRING(name, 1, 4)FROM person;
```

I cant figure out what I am missing, any help?

Comment: You should use UPDATE not SELECT in the last statement.

Comment: Try and use `VARCHAR(255)` as a default and only restrict that if you have a very compelling reason. For many things, like names and email addresses, shorter fields can cause huge hassles for your users.

Comment: I realize that, but im being asked to do this with insert into

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want an update query, not an insert:

```
update user4 set username = concat(first_name, ' ', last_name);
```

Or you could simply compute the new column on the fly when creating the new table:

```
create table user4 AS Select p.*, concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) username from person p
```

Comment: your solution works, but im being asked to use insert into